# ASP.NET Open Source Solution

Tags: asp.net, open-source, instantmessenger

i am looking for an open source Solution for a company.
For example we have a management Unit. and some Departments (for example 20).
i am looking for a system that enable me to this :
clients (Departments) can send Request as text message to Management Unit and Server can Answer them.
abstract : an Open Source Offline messenger.
is there any suggestions?
thanks.
**UPDATE :
a web base system that enable me to send and receive Messages between some computers in Lan network.**

Comment: It is entirely unclear what you are looking for. An SMS solution? Something else? Hierarchy management?

Comment: Sounds like you could simply use emails?

Comment: Are you looking for message queue system?

Comment: @ShahidAzim : Something like this (message queue system.)

Comment: @Oded : not SMS Solution. A web base solution to send and receive Messages (Requests as text) between some Computers in network .

Comment: @citronas i can use email but i want a open source system that i can extend that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution would be to use .NET to write messages to Jabber. Obviously, the consumers will need a Jabber client.

[jabber-net](http://code.google.com/p/jabber-net/)

Answer (score 0):

This is a good starting point to use message queue using ASP.NET:

http://www.15seconds.com/issue/031202.htm